# Showing that an increasing and continuous function's inverse is increasing and continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, inverse-function

Show that if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and increasing, then the inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists and is also continuous and increasing on the interval on which it is defined.

---

*Proof*

**Show that $f$ is one-to-one**

Since $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$, for each $x_n \in [a,b]$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(x_n)<f(x_{n+1})$

Then if $f(x_n)<f(x_{n+1}), \Rightarrow x_n<x_{n+1}$

So when $f(x_n)\neq f(x_{n+1}), \Rightarrow x_n \neq x_{n+1}$. Thus, $f$ is one-to-one

**Show that $f$ is onto**

Take $y \in f([a,b])$

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ we can find an $x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=y$ for all $y \in f([a,b])$

Thus, $f$ is onto

**Since $f$ is one-to-one and onto, $f$ is bijective, which means $f^{-1}$ exists**

Now, since $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$, $f^{-1}$ is defined on the interval $[f(a),f(b)]$

We know that $(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ by the inverse function theorem which tells us that if $f'>0$ on an interval, then $(f^{-1})'>0$ on that interval.

Since $f$ is increasing on $[a,b], f'(x)>0$ on $[a,b]$. Then $(f^{-1}){'}(x)>0$ on $[a,b]$

Thus, $f^{-1}$ is increasing.

I can't figure out how to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous based off of all this.

---

I feel like this proof is full of mistakes so feel free to show me where I'm going wrong. I'm having trouble seeing all this.

Comment: It is not true that if $f$ is continuous and increasing on $[a,b]$, then $f'(x) > 0$ on $[a,b]$. First of all, it's not necessarily true that $f'(x)$ exists for any $x \in [a,b]$. Second, a function like $f(x) = x^3$ over $[0,1]$ satisfies $f'(a) = 0$.

Comment: Your proof of "onto" needs more detail.

Comment: On an intuitive level (i.e. **informally**) the **well defined** inverse function (**if it exists**) is nothing more than the reflection of $f(x)$ about the line $y = x$.

Comment: It's sufficient that $f$ is increasing, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301285/prove-that-if-f-is-strictly-increasing-on-i-then-f-has-a-continuous-inver/2301405#2301405

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $f$ is strictly increasing on $I$, then $f$ has a continuous inverse.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301285/prove-that-if-f-is-strictly-increasing-on-i-then-f-has-a-continuous-inver)

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly established that $f^{-1}$ exists.

Now, use the definition of "increasing" to conclude that $f^{-1}$ is increasing.

From there, use the definition of continuity. Consider any $y \in (f(a),f(b))$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. We want to show that there is a $\delta > 0$ for which
$$
|y - y'| < \delta \implies |f^{-1}(y) - f^{-1}(y')| < \epsilon.
$$
Let $x = f^{-1}(y)$. Define $y_1 = f(x- \epsilon)$ and $y_2 = f(x + \epsilon)$. Let $\delta = \min\{y - y_1, y_2 - y\}$. We note that for any $y'$ with $|y - y'| < \delta$, we have
$$
y_1 < y' < y_2 \implies f^{-1}(y_1) < f^{-1}(y') < f^{-1}(y_2) 
\\\implies f^{-1}(y) - \epsilon < f^{-1}(y')
< f^{-1}(y) + \epsilon\\
\implies |f^{-1}(y') - f^{-1}(y)| < \epsilon,
$$
which is what we wanted.

The proof where $y$ is equal to either endpoint is similar.